# Date.prototype.Format() method for local time in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, date, timezone, timestamp

Here is an example:

```
Date.prototype.Format = function(fmt)
{ 
    var o = {
        "M+" : this.getMonth()+1,                 //
        "d+" : this.getDate(),                    //
        "h+" : this.getHours(),                   //
        "m+" : this.getMinutes(),                 //
        "s+" : this.getSeconds(),                 //
        "q+" : Math.floor((this.getMonth()+3)/3), //
        "S"  : this.getMilliseconds()             //
    };
    if(/(y+)/.test(fmt))
        fmt=fmt.replace(RegExp.$1, (this.getFullYear()+"").substr(4 - RegExp.$1.length));
    for(var k in o)
        if(new RegExp("("+ k +")").test(fmt))
            fmt = fmt.replace(RegExp.$1, (RegExp.$1.length==1) ? (o[k]) : (("00"+ o[k]).substr((""+ o[k]).length)));
    return fmt;
}
new Date(1).Format("yyyy/MM/dd hh/mm")
```

I found the hour `hh` here will be formated to the Hour in **UTC time**. Is there a way to print the hour in **local time** using some specific string in Format, such as

```
new Date(1).Format("Localyyyy/LocalMM/Localdd Localhh/Localmm")
```

It will be better if it has browser compatibility.

Comment: What library are you using that provides this `Format` method?

Comment: @Bergi just the naive Javascript..

Comment: naive this may be, but there is not native `.Format` method on [`Date` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Or what Javascript are you talking about? Please link the docs for that method.

Comment: @Bergi Ok, I just found it is a third-party function instead of native function...  Is there any widely-used library? Or is there any best practice to deal with Date Formating?

Comment: Accessing `RegExp.$1`? Whoa that's old, outdated code. But no, your `Format` method does indeed use the methods that access your date objects in the local format (not the `getUTC…` ones). So it is likely that you are instead constructing your `Date` object in the wrong way if they are representing the wrong time. Please show us that code as well.

Comment: This function looks flawed in a few ways...  Have you considered [moment.js](http://momentjs.com)?